# Why do convolutional deep learning models produce different FPS for different scenes?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, nvidia, frame-rate

I have a model that inputs image (448x448) and outputs steering angle. As my observation, FPS (frame per second) of system varies depending on the image scene. For example, if image input is a rainy scene, system outputs predictions in 20 FPS. However if image input is sunny scene, system outputs predictions in 30FPS. And complexity of image is effecting FPS too.

Why do the FPS of predictions ​​change depending on the scene conditions, even though the same calculations are made for each picture in the CNNs? What could be the reason of this difference?

I expect same FPS from CNN model for every image input. But it is not stable.

Comment: What king of network do you use ? With region proposal approaches, this could happen : if you have many regions proposed, you have to analyze them all and therefore lose a lot of precious fps ;)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/0bserver07/Nvidia-Autopilot-Keras/raw/master/imgs/9-layer-ConvNet-model.png) image shows my model architecture. It is not a region proposal network as far as I know. My network contains convolution and dense layers. Do you have any idea? Best regards.

Comment: @JosephBudin I just realize that I am using FP16 precision mode while inferencing with deep learning model. Is it possible to affect FPS of the model by presicion mode? I started to think that the source of the non-determinism is floating point operations when I see [this](http://www.shorturl.at/ixMSV) comment :
_"If your code uses floating-point atomics, results may differ from run to run because floating-point operations are generally not associative, and the order in which data enters a computation (e.g. a sum) is non-deterministic when atomics are used."_

Comment: I would find it surprising that the floating point operation differ depending on the content of the image. Do you use different datasets for rainy/sunny ?

Comment: @JosephBudin The dataset which I used in training and testing is contains images from various scenes (There is no different datasets). Similar to the "difference of FPSs of rainy/sunny scenes" problem; when the same input is given to the model, it produces _same prediction_ and **different FPS** values.